# Google Chrome Socket API in extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So after developing an extension for a few hours, assuming that the chrome.socket API would be available to extensions, I load in my extension and I'm told that the Socket API is only available for 'Packaged Apps'.

Does anyone know what's happening, and whether extensions will get the feature (back, since I think they had access when it was in .experimental)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [Chrome docs](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network.html):

> **Packaged apps** can act as a network client for TCP and UDP connections.

No, extensions do not have access to the socket API, and they aren't likely to ever get it.

Your confusion is understandable, since what Google called "packaged apps" used to be nothing but glorified extensions with an icon on the home screen. However, Google is now driving a much wider divide between extensions and apps.

Extensions used to have a subset of the functionality the apps did, but now there is mutually exclusive functionality in each. Extensions are meant for enhancing normal Web browsing, whereas apps are meant to be used as stand-alone tools that do not interfere with normal browsing. If you look at the API lists for [apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index.html) and for [extensions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html), you'll see that the list is *vastly* different: apps have the powerful hardware- and OS-centric APIs like `socket`, `usb`, and `bluetooth`, while extensions have a monopoly on browser-centric APIs like `tabs`, `cookies`, and `bookmarks`.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the part of the text, I missed that. I'd still like to know more about why, and what any plans are. I've filed a bug to try to find out, and will report here if I get a reply.

Comment: @Tom: What was the bug report ID/URL, if you still have it? I was about to file one. (Yes, it's 2016, and things haven't changed...)

Comment: @i336_ Sorry, I don't have it easily available. I only saw now that this question has had over 2.5k views!

Comment: @Tom That's absolutely fine. Considering how long it's been, it doesn't look like this is going to change in Chrome. Ah well.